# EntityFrameworkCore does not exist - VS2017 - UWP

Tags: visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

I just installed VS2017 Enterprise, attempted to create blank UWP project.
Then I added a class derived from DbContext

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Test
{
    public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
    }
}
```

The compiler does not like the simple class above and complained that:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Although I did install the sqlite package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
```

And the installation was successful.

What have I missed? Maybe I need to add reference to a dll but which dll should I use?

**Update:**
I tried to install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (the main package) as suggested but it seems to be incompatible.

```
supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10240 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) / win10-arm. Package 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10240 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) / win10-arm-aot. Package 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10240 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) / win10-x64. Package 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10240 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) / win10-x64-aot. Package 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10240 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) / win10-x86. Package 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10240 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) / win10-x86-aot. Package 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'TestEntityFW'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install also main package of EF Core

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
```

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite is only db provider package for Entity Framework Core like for example Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.

Comment: I do not think I can install the main package EntityFrameworkCore because it seems to be incompatible with UWP. See my update

Comment: so you must use latest visual studio https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/25/uwp-net-standard-2-0-preview/ or you can't use Entity Framework Core  because main package of Entity Framework Core is required to develop

Comment: @MateuszWk6: I see. From the link provided, I have to have min version of 16299, I only have the 10240. That is probably the issue. I do have the latest version of VS2017 mentioned in the link

Comment: You don't need to install main package explicitly if you are installing one of the provider packages.